# TCL delete the content in the range of matched regexp

Tags: tcl

I am having one input file as stated below

```
module bist_logic_inst(a, ab , dhd, dhdh , djdj, hdh, djjd, jdj, dhd, dhp, dk
);
input a;
input ab;
input dhd;
input djdj;
input dhd;
output hdh;
output djjd;
output jdj;
output dk;
// MBIST Structures 
mvusr1 ssbs1:dhdhd ala;
hheh ls djd : kdkd akk;

);


bist_reverse_mapper Umbist_reverse_inst(  .BIST_SO(), .BIST_SO_ts1(), .BIST_SO_ts2(), .BIST_SO_ts3(), .BIST_GO(), .BIST_GO_ts1(), 
      .BIST_GO_ts2(), .BIST_GO_ts3(), .clk_mbist(), .BIST_SETUP(), .ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en(), 
      .MEM0_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM1_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM2_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM3_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), 
      .bistEn(), .BIST_COLLAR_DIAG_EN(), .ltest_to_en(), .BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE(), 
      .BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE(), .BIST_SELECT(), .BIST_WRITEENABLE()
  );

endmodule
```

I need to delete the content in between //MBIST Structures and );

My output file should be

```
module bist_logic_inst(a, ab , dhd, dhdh , djdj, hdh, djjd, jdj, dhd, dhp, dk
);
input a;
input ab;
input dhd;
input djdj;
input dhd;
output hdh;
output djjd;
output jdj;
output dk;



bist_reverse_mapper Umbist_reverse_inst(  .BIST_SO(), .BIST_SO_ts1(), .BIST_SO_ts2(), .BIST_SO_ts3(), .BIST_GO(), .BIST_GO_ts1(), 
      .BIST_GO_ts2(), .BIST_GO_ts3(), .clk_mbist(), .BIST_SETUP(), .ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en(), 
      .MEM0_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM1_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM2_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), .MEM3_BIST_COLLAR_SI(), 
      .bistEn(), .BIST_COLLAR_DIAG_EN(), .ltest_to_en(), .BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE(), 
      .BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE(), .BIST_SELECT(), .BIST_WRITEENABLE()
  );

endmodule
```

I know how to extract the range but that will not help me to delete the content in between the regexps

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file in as a single string (with the `read` command), then you can use `regsub` on that string. Use the pattern `// MBIST Structures.*?\);` and replace it with an empty string (Note the non-greedy quantifier `*?`).